# Express sub-apps not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make my main app be able to dynamically add other sub-apps so that I can do something like '/user/appName' where appName is the name of the sub-app. In my project directory I have an 'apps' directory that will contain all the sub-apps (they will all have their own app.js). I made a simple function to do this and it works if I comment out all the error handling stuff. However, I would still like to use error handling.

I call the useApp function from a post method in the main app.

I've search and tried many things, but can't find anything where someone is trying to do something similar. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var admin = require('./routes/administrator');
var networkView = require('./routes/networkView');

var app = express();

//view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

/** if you want hogan to use ".html" file extension
app.engine('html', require('hjs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
**/

app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/networkView', networkView);

// import a sub app
function useApp(appName) {
    app.use('/user/' + appName, require('./apps/' + appName + '/app'));
}

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

exports.useApp = useApp;
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on how express works. The problem is that the app.use() in my function adds the route to the end of the stack. And therefore is not reachable. I came up with the following solution:

```
/**
 * function that allows sub apps to be added to this app dynamically (when the server is running)
 * @param appName
 */
function useApp(appName) {
    // add the route
    app.use('/user/' + appName, require('./apps/' + appName + '/app'));

    // put the new route before the 404 catch on the router stack
    // this assumes there are 3 other routes after this one (len - 4)
    var last = app._router.stack[app._router.stack.length - 1];
    delete app._router.stack[app._router.stack.length - 1];
    app._router.stack.splice(app._router.stack.length - 4, 0, last);
}
```

It moves the new route in the proper location in the stack, so it becomes reachable.

Not sure if it's the best approach, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've built something to accomplish just that. Feel free to take a look:

https://github.com/tkiddle/expressPlate/tree/tkiddle

Make sure you're on the "tkiddle" branch.